# Can't add date to archive

Tags: ms-access

I have duplicated a Table to create an Archive table, and for some reason I can't make to Appending Query to work.
This is the SQL code:

```
INSERT INTO tblArc
SELECT tblCostumer.*
FROM tblCostumer, tblArc
WHERE (((tblArc.num)=[Enter Client Number you'd like to move to the archive]));
```

When I enter the costumer number, it says "You are about to append 0 row(s)" instead of appending 1 row.

Answer (score 1):

That `FROM` clause would give you a [cross join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_join#Cross_join), which is probably not what you should really want ...

```sql
FROM tblCostumer, tblArc
```

Instead `SELECT` only from `tblCostumer` based on its primary key.  For example, if the primary key is `tblCostumer.num` ...

```sql
INSERT INTO tblArc
SELECT tblCostumer.*
FROM tblCostumer
WHERE tblCostumer.num=[Enter Client Number you'd like to move to the archive];
```

And if the structures of the two tables are not the same, list the specific fields instead of ...

```sql
INSERT INTO tblArc
SELECT tblCostumer.*
```